# How to fix "SDL_Init failed -1" in buildroot Raspberry image?

Tags: sdl, raspberry-pi3, buildroot, navit

I'm trying to compile Navit for Raspberry Pi 3 with Buildroot image (WPE Framework included). There is only WPE Framework running on startup (no x server) therefore I would like to display Navit using framebuffer directly. I know there is support for this feature. I have configured Navit as follow:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDZ3O.png
but I'm not able to run it anyway. There is following error:
    `error:graphics_sdl:graphics_sdl_new:SDL_Init failed -1`
I've installed SDL from buildroot. How to fix it or make SDL more verbose to find out what is the reason of this -1 error (missing dependencies, incompatible lib version, Navit configration problems, missing system variables pointing to specified dependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Navit is very quiet about SDL error messages. -1 Error is just very general information... I had to recompile Navit sources and add SDL_GetError() function to code to find out what is a real reason.
The problem was missing mouse. I don't need it so I had to set up:

> export SDL_NOMOUSE=1